# Is there a a way to make this function calculate sd as well as mean?

Tags: r

```
setNames(apply(cats, 1, , na.rm = TRUE), df[[1]]))
```

I would like `mean` and `sd` to be outputted by one function.

Comment: What about `f <- function(x) c(m = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), s = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))` and then `sapply(iris[, 1:2], f)` ?

Comment: what does apply(iris[, 1:2], f) do?  as doesn't that make it two functions?

Comment: Didn't you write "I would like mean and sd to be outputted by **one function**."? That is what `f` does, no?

Comment: yeah but if the sapply(iris[, 1:2], f) is needed to output it and thats a separate line of code then its not the same function is it? i may be wrong i am not the most versed in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length), list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), 
         sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
#      mean        sd
#1 5.843333 0.8280661
```

Comment: @ash7on not clear about your comment.  can you be a bit more specific.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is supposed to do `cats` in your example.  So I will follow the title of your post.

With `data.table`, you can do complex calculations with `lapply` + `.SD` verbs in just one line :

```r
library(data.table)
df = data.table(iris)
df[,lapply(.SD, function(x) return(c(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)))), .SDcols = colnames(df)[1]]
#  Sepal.Length
# 1:    5.8433333
# 2:    0.8280661
```

You can do that for more than one column if wanted

Comment: I updated the answer to give some precisions I had not given